# Slow page with html5 videos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video.js

Each slide has a background video.
the problem is that the page does not work very well, it is a bit slow on older pc and mac and I would like to **optimize it**.

*I do not mean when you load the page** but the operation of the page itself, when you are scrolling it seems that all the videos are activated and this causes the page to become **heavy slow** on older pc and mac.

I'm using video.js for the background videos.

any idea how to optimize it?

here is a page example: http://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_video/

html:

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-container-home">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <article class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-slide-content swiper-slide-content-intro">
        <h2>And you can clean around the wound <br>
        If you want to, It just takes time</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="fullscreen-video">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-close icon-close-video"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- the autoplay is only for the first video -->
      <video id="my-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay loop muted playsinline> 
        <source type="video/mp4" src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/422535408.hd.mp4?s=15cc550deb01f3addbfd31fbfd0a63ee665800d8&profile_id=174">
      </video>
      <div class="scrolldown fakt-light text small"></div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
/* home page */
$(window).load(function() {

  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: -1,
    mousewheel: true,
    preventClicks: true,
    allowTouchMove: true,
    preventClicksPropagation: true
  });

  swiper.on('slideChange', function() {
    var realIndex = swiper.realIndex;
    if (realIndex == 0) {
      $("#header").removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $("#header").addClass("active");
    }
  });

  // next slide
  $(".scrolldown").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.slideNext();
      return !1;
  });

  $(".swiper-slide, .swiper-container").height($(window).height());
  $(window).resize(function () {
      $(".swiper-slide, .swiper-container").height($(window).height());
  });

  function toggleMute() {
      $(".swiper-slide-active .play_video").on("click", function (e) {
          var video = $(".swiper-slide-active video").attr("id");
          var play = videojs(video);
          console.log(video);
          e.preventDefault();
          $(".content").removeClass("delay");
          $("body").addClass("music_on");
          play.currentTime(0);
          play.play();
          play.muted(!1);
          play.on("ended", function () {
              $("body").removeClass("music_on");
              play.muted(!0);
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $(".content").addClass("delay");
              }, 1000);
          });
          return !1;
      });
      $(".swiper-slide-active .cross_video").on("click", function (e) {
          var video = $(".swiper-slide-active video").attr("id");
          var player = videojs(video);
          player.muted(!0);
          $("body").removeClass("music_on");
          setTimeout(function () {
              $(".content").addClass("delay");
          }, 1000);
      });
      $(".swiper-slide-active")
          .not(".play_video")
          .on("click", function () {
              var video = $(".swiper-slide-active video").attr("id");
              var player = videojs(video);
              player.muted(!0);
              $("body").removeClass("music_on");
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $(".content").addClass("delay");
              }, 1000);
          });
      $(document).keyup(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 27) {
              var video = $(".swiper-slide-active video").attr("id");
              var player = videojs(video);
              player.muted(!0);
              $("body").removeClass("music_on");
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $(".content").addClass("delay");
              }, 1000);
          }
      });
  }
  if ($(".swiper-slide-active video").length) {
      var video = $(".swiper-slide-active video").attr("id");
      var player = videojs(video);
      player.play();
      player.muted(!0);
      toggleMute();
  }
  swiper.on("slideChangeTransitionStart", function () {
      $("body").removeClass("music_on");
      if ($(".swiper-slide-active video").length) {
          var video = $(".swiper-slide-active video").attr("id");
          var player = videojs(video);
          player.play();
          player.muted(!0);
          toggleMute();
      }
  });
  swiper.on("slideChangeTransitionEnd", function () {
      if ($(".swiper-slide-prev video").length) {
          var video = $(".swiper-slide-prev video").attr("id");
          var player = videojs(video);
          player.play();
          player.muted(!0);
      }
      if ($(".swiper-slide-next video").length) {
          var video = $(".swiper-slide-next video").attr("id");
          var player = videojs(video);
          player.play();
          player.muted(!0);
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amm I dont think it is for js
I dont know about your internet speed
But I guess it is your video Problem
Your Video is redirecting and so you are feeling that the site is slow.
Watch this [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks1Mf.png)

I think Just download the Video and then you compress it by any online or offline tools.
turn it 10mb to 1-2mb

also use the Cache-Control Headers for your server

[Watch this](https://kinsta.com/blog/leverage-browser-caching/) For how to.
I think your will be solved.
Thank You

[Update]
You can also link those js files which were hosted in google server.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you just need to not do this.

Find a better way to present what you want without having a ton of HD videos in the background.  You'll need fallback content anyway, for people who aren't going to play your videos (perhaps on bandwidth restricted networks).

Some devices can't even decode more than one video at a time, much less decode, scale, playback, composite, and handle some JavaScript-based smooth scrolling at the same time.  Even on my beefy laptop, your site only plays one video at a time for me.

At a minimum, you'll want to pause any videos not currently on-screen.  Try to play only one thing at a time.

Comment: Yes, I think that to start it would be best to reproduce only one video at a time, I thought that my code was doing that, can you help me with it?